# What is the comparable interface called?

Tags: go, interface, linked-list, comparison-operators

I'm working on a simple linked list implementation in Go for learning purposes.  The definition of an element is below:

```
type Element struct {
    next, prev *Element
    Value      interface{}
}
```

As you can see, the Value can be anything that satisfies the empty interface.  Now, as a new feature, I would like to make it so that when you insert a new element into the list, it inserts it in a sorted manner - each element will be <= the next.

In order to do this, I wrote the following method:

```
func (l *LinkedList) Add(val interface{}) *Element {
    this := &l.Root
    e := Element{Value: val}
    for {
        if this.next.Value != nil && this.next.Value < val {  // <-comparison here
            this = this.next
        } else {
            return l.insert(&e, this)
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains `operator < not defined on interface` which is fair.  So I understand that in my Element typedef, I should restrict Value to types that can be compared using the `<` operator.  I learned this while researching this problem that Go does not support operator overloading - I am not trying to do that.  Instead, I am just trying to make sure that Element.Value is a type that can be compared using the `<` operator. How do I do this?

### Update:

It occurs to me that it might not be too difficult to simple define a new type, based on a built-in, that can be compared through some function.  so I wrote this mess (as well as a bunch of other ways of trying to do the same thing):

```
type Comparable interface {
    LessThan(j interface{}) bool // tried (j Comparable), (j MyInt), etc
    EqualTo(j interface{}) bool  // tried (j Comparable), (j MyInt), etc
}

type MyInt int

func (i MyInt) LessThan(j MyInt) bool {
    return i < j
}

func (i MyInt) EqualTo(j MyInt) bool {
    return i == j
}

type Element struct {
    next, prev *Element
    Value      Comparable
}
```

What I would really like is to define an interface, which, if implemented for a type, provides functions `LessThan` and `EqualTo` that operate on two instances of that type and provides a bool - something like `LessThan(i, j WhatEvers) bool` which can be used in place of `<`.  I realize below it's implemented as an instance method - I've tried both ways but no success.  With the above, I would use it something like: `this.next.Value.LessThan(val)` in the Add function.  I get either:

```
linkedlist.MyInt does not implement linkedlist.Comparable (wrong type for EqualTo method)
    have EqualTo(linkedlist.MyInt) bool
    want EqualTo(interface {}) bool
```

or

```
linkedlist.MyInt does not implement linkedlist.Comparable (wrong type for EqualTo method)
    have EqualTo(linkedlist.MyInt) bool
    want EqualTo(linkedlist.Comparable) bool
```

Is this possible to use an interface to require that a certain function must exist that operates on two instances of a custom type, or is it only for Methods?

Comment: Have you taken a look at how the standard [linked list](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) and [sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) implementations handle this?

Comment: You can't. There is no such type like "everything which allows comparison via <".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:
consider this user type:

```
type userType struct {
    frequency int
    value     rune
}
```

and suppose you want to add this types to your Linked List:
and It should be sorted by frequency first, then if the frequencies are the same, look at the char value. so the `Compare` function will be:

```
func (a userType) Compare(b userType) int {
    if a.frequency > b.frequency {
        return 1
    }
    if a.frequency < b.frequency {
        return -1
    }
    if a.value > b.value {
        return 1
    }
    if a.value < b.value {
        return -1
    }
    return 0
}
```

which satisfies this interface:

```
type Comparer interface {
    Compare(b userType) int
}
```

now add these `{1,'d'} {2,'b'} {3,'c'} {4,'a'} {4,'b'} {4,'c'}` types to LinkeList:
sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type Comparer interface {
    Compare(b userType) int
}

type userType struct {
    frequency int
    value     rune
}

// it should sort by frequency first, then if the frequencies are the same, look at the char value.
func (a userType) Compare(b userType) int {
    if a.frequency > b.frequency {
        return 1
    }
    if a.frequency < b.frequency {
        return -1
    }
    if a.value > b.value {
        return 1
    }
    if a.value < b.value {
        return -1
    }
    return 0
}

func Insert(val userType, l *list.List) {
    e := l.Front()
    if e == nil {
        l.PushFront(val)
        return
    }
    for ; e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        var ut userType = e.Value.(userType)
        if val.Compare(ut) < 0 {
            l.InsertBefore(val, e)
            return
        }
    }
    l.PushBack(val)
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    Insert(userType{4, 'c'}, l)
    Insert(userType{4, 'a'}, l)
    Insert(userType{4, 'b'}, l)
    Insert(userType{2, 'b'}, l)
    Insert(userType{3, 'c'}, l)
    Insert(userType{1, 'd'}, l)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        ut := e.Value.(userType)
        fmt.Printf("{%d,%q} ", ut.frequency, ut.value)
    }
    fmt.Println()

    var t interface{} = userType{4, 'c'}
    i, ok := t.(Comparer)
    fmt.Println(i, ok)
}
```

and output:

```
{1,'d'} {2,'b'} {3,'c'} {4,'a'} {4,'b'} {4,'c'} 
{4 99} true
```

---

so if you ready to use known type (e.g. `int`), see this sample:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func Insert(val int, l *list.List) {
    e := l.Front()
    if e == nil {
        l.PushFront(val)
        return
    }
    for ; e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        v := e.Value.(int)
        if val < v {
            l.InsertBefore(val, e)
            return
        }
    }
    l.PushBack(val)
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    Insert(4, l)
    Insert(2, l)
    Insert(3, l)
    Insert(1, l)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Print(e.Value, " ") // 1 2 3 4
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

---

old:

There is no such interface in Go. You may write this `Less` function to compare your types:

```
func Less(a, b interface{}) bool {
    switch a.(type) {
    case int:
        if ai, ok := a.(int); ok {
            if bi, ok := b.(int); ok {
                return ai < bi
            }
        }
    case string:
        if ai, ok := a.(string); ok {
            if bi, ok := b.(string); ok {
                return ai < bi
            }
        }
    // ...
    default:
        panic("Unknown")
    }
    return false
}
```

test sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func Less(a, b interface{}) bool {
    switch a.(type) {
    case int:
        if ai, ok := a.(int); ok {
            if bi, ok := b.(int); ok {
                return ai < bi
            }
        }
    case string:
        if ai, ok := a.(string); ok {
            if bi, ok := b.(string); ok {
                return ai < bi
            }
        }
    default:
        panic("Unknown")
    }
    return false
}

func Insert(val interface{}, l *list.List) *list.Element {
    e := l.Front()
    if e == nil {
        return l.PushFront(val)
    }
    for ; e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        if Less(val, e.Value) {
            return l.InsertBefore(val, e)
        }
    }
    return l.PushBack(val)
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()

    Insert(4, l)
    Insert(2, l)
    Insert(3, l)
    Insert(1, l)
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Print(e.Value, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()

    Insert("C", l)
    Insert("A", l)
    Insert("AB", l)
    Insert("C", l)
    Insert("C2", l)
    Insert("C1", l)

    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Print(e.Value, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 A AB C C C1 C2
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am trying to do.  I do not want to sort a constructed List.  AFAIK, `sort.Interface` is implemented on the container.  I need to ensure elements are comparable.

Comment: @domoarrigato: see new edit, if you provide minimum working sample code, i could help more.

Comment: I think the point is that `Value` is not a "new type" so they can't add a `Compare` function to it.

Comment: I thought about defining a `Comparable` interface of my own, but as I understand it, that would mean it is not possible to use simple native types as Values, since they do not implement this new interface. when I tried, I got `cannot define new methods on non-local type int`

Comment: then using `reflect` package is the answer

Comment: @Amd could you elaborate?

Comment: @domoarrigato: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693619/golang-implementing-a-linked-list

Comment: @Amd - i updated the question.  I know I originally said I didn't want to define an interface, but after seeing the type assertion method you wrote - I think it's just not a way that I like - I don't think it's right to have to test types at runtime - too many branches - especially if I later *do* want to use custom types as Values.  Since I cant do what I originally wanted to, seems like the best bet is the custom interface - but having some trouble there too.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible answer I have been able to make work, but it's so ugly, (reduces every comparison to an int value - might work for strings, but will be bloody hard for other types) - I don't want to accept it:

```
type MyInt int

type Valuer interface {
    ValueOf() int
}

func LessThan(i, j Valuer) bool {
    return i.ValueOf() < j.ValueOf()
}

func EqualTo(i, j Valuer) bool {
    return i.ValueOf() == j.ValueOf()
}

func (i MyInt) ValueOf() int {
    return int(i)
}

type Element struct {
    next, prev *Element
    Value      Valuer
}
```

someone please tell me there is a better way!