# How one can do case insensitive sorting using sort.Strings() in Golang?

Tags: sorting, go

Is there any way to pass the custom function in the sort.Strings() to do the case-insensitive sorting on the list of strings?

```
data := []string{"A", "b", "D", "c"}
```

The output should be: A, b, c, D

The equivalent of the above requirement in Python is like :

```
li = sorted(data, key=lambda s: s.lower())
```

Do we have something like that in golang?

Comment: I don't think there's any inbuilt function for that kind of sort, but you can always create your own sort, with that sorting criteria.

Comment: You can also use a comparable interface with your sort, like explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122919/what-is-the-comparable-interface-called-in-golang). Since, you are not using any `struct`, you can make a simple string comparable interface.

Comment: Thank you @MaJoR, I am aware of that way, thought like if i can do this by inbuilt function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The translation of the Python code to Go is:

```
sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool { return strings.ToLower(data[i]) < strings.ToLower(data[j]) })
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DfzriYi4im5).

This approach, like the Python code in the question, can allocate two strings for each comparison. The allocations are probably OK for the example in the question, but can be a problem in other scenarios.

To avoid allocations, compare the strings rune by rune:

```
func lessLower(sa, sb string) bool {
    for {
        rb, nb := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(sb)
        if nb == 0 {
            // The number of runes in sa is greater than or 
            // equal to the number of runes in sb. It follows
            // that sa is not less than sb.
            return false
        }

        ra, na := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(sa)
        if na == 0 {
            // The number of runes in sa is less than the
            // number of runes in sb. It follows that sa
            // is less than sb.
            return true
        }

        rb = unicode.ToLower(rb)
        ra = unicode.ToLower(ra)

        if ra != rb {
            return ra < rb
        }

        // Trim rune from the beginning of each string.
        sa = sa[na:]
        sb = sb[nb:]
    }
}
⋮
sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool { return lessLower(data[i], data[j]) })
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/q3MQexS8cRn).

Take a look at the [collate package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/collate) if you need to sort by language or culture specific sort orders.

Answer (score 2):

The solution below is more verbose and more performant. The main difference is that in the other answers, using [strings.ToLower](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ToLower) at each comparison allocates some memory, and the code below takes care of comparing runes without creating any new string.

```
// lessCaseInsensitive compares s, t without allocating
func lessCaseInsensitive(s, t string) bool {
    for {
        if len(t) == 0 {
            return false
        }
        if len(s) == 0 {
            return true
        }
        c, sizec := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
        d, sized := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(t)

        lowerc := unicode.ToLower(c)
        lowerd := unicode.ToLower(d)

        if lowerc < lowerd {
            return true
        }
        if lowerc > lowerd {
            return false
        }

        s = s[sizec:]
        t = t[sized:]
    }
}

sort.Slice(data, func(i, j int) bool { return lessCaseInsensitive(data[i], data[j]) })
```

You can see in [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/Deleplace/8a9224f8b2838a9c1d112acde5bdd3c8) for example that avoiding allocs makes the case-insensitive sorting 5x faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need a type that implements [sort.Interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

https://play.golang.org/p/JTm0AjuxCRV

Comment: Thank you Nirmal, I also implemented the requirement in the same way. Was looking the solution in the one-liner or so as last response.

Comment: Yeah, the method suggested by ThunderCat seems much easier.

Comment: This is the old style.

Comment: @NirmalAgrawal comparing only the 1st rune of each string (with `[0]`) is not sufficient, see e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/g_qkBa3yBSQ . Also "byLength" is not the best type name for this. Also, it panics on an empty string.