# golang sort function does not sort string slice

Tags: sorting, go

I have following code

```
m := map[string][]string{
    "LaptopPro": {"M1-pro", "M2"},
    "Speaker":   {"klipsch"},
    "dev":       {"ddd"},
    "dv":        {"ddd"},
    "laptop":    {"m1", "m2"},
    "laptop99":  {"m1", "m2"},
}

keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}

sort.Strings(keys)

for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println(k, m[k])
}
```

But the output is:

```
LaptopPro [M1-pro M2]
Speaker [klipsch]
dev [ddd]
dv [ddd]
laptop [m1 m2]
laptop99 [m1 m2]
```

Which is definitely not sorted.Why is this happening?

Comment: It is sorted. Capital letters come before lowercase letters. Maybe you wanted to do case-insensitive sort?

Comment: Yes @BurakSerdar , that is exactly what I wanna do. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks for the note @BurakSerdar

Comment: Use `sort.Slice`, and compare after upper/lowercasing the strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Burak noted, I wanted case-insensitive sort. I searched again includeing `case-insensitive` phrase and here's the solution I have found:

```
sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool { return strings.ToLower(keys[i]) < strings.ToLower(keys[j]) })
```

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997907/1626977

Answer (score 0):

It did.

```
keys before:

[laptop laptop99 LaptopPro Speaker dev dv] 



keys after:

LaptopPro [M1-pro M2]
Speaker [klipsch]
dev [ddd]
dv [ddd]
laptop [m1 m2]
laptop99 [m1 m2]
```

First Go will sort uppercase, and lowercase in the end